# How to copy image from another sheet to active sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I've inserted some images into `Sheet2` and I'd like to copy them into my `Sheet1`(that will be ActieSheet). That image copy will be executed when I type image names in column1 after 5th row on `Sheet1`. I've tried few things but they don't work, however, I've assembled few lines of code or the way that I'd like it to be implemented. Here it is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim picName As String

    If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row >= 5 Then
        picName = Target.Offset(0, 0).Value

        'Here goes the rest of the code

    End If

End Sub
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim picName As String
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row >= 5 Then
        picName = Target.Value
        Copy_Images picName
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Copy_Images(imageName As String)
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In Sheets(2).Shapes
        If sh.Name = imageName Then
            sh.Copy
            Sheets(1).Pictures.Paste
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Nice and clear and also got me to the notice that I need to change default image names to the one that I'd like to use.