# Copying Image With Worksheet Using Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro in VBA which opens another workbook and copies a worksheet across into the active workbook, then closes the worksheet again.

This all works fine, except that the images included in the worksheet do not copy across. I get a placeholder where the image ought to be, displaying the text "This image cannot currently be displayed".

When I do the same procedure manually, the images copy across without a problem.

Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it?

Edit: code below.

```
Sub copy_sheet()

Dim wbk_current As Workbook
Set wbk_current = ActiveWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim lastdate As String, filename As String

lastdate = Format(wbk_current.Worksheets(1).Range("D11") - 7, "ddmmyy")
filename = "C:\Folder\Filename " & lastdate & ".xlsx"

Dim wbk_old As Workbook
Set wbk_old = Workbooks.Open(filename)

wbk_old.Worksheets(2).Copy after:=wbk_current.Worksheets(1)
wbk_old.Close

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = wbk_current.Worksheets(2).UsedRange.Rows.Count
weekrange = Format(wbk_current.Worksheets(1).Range("C11"), "dd/mm/yy") & " - " & Format(wbk_current.Worksheets(1).Range("D11"), "dd/mm/yy")

wbk_current.Worksheets(2).Rows(lastrow - 1 & ":" & lastrow - 1).Copy
wbk_current.Worksheets(2).Rows(lastrow & ":" & lastrow).Insert shift:=xlDown

wbk_current.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & lastrow).Value = wbk_current.Worksheets(2).Range("B" & lastrow - 1).Value + 1
wbk_current.Worksheets(2).Range("C" & lastrow) = weekrange
wbk_current.Worksheets(2).Range("D" & lastrow & ":J" & lastrow).Value = wbk_current.Worksheets(1).Range("C16:I16").Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

(The first 15 or so lines are the relevant ones.)

As far as I'm aware, this should do exactly the same thing as doing it manually - I'm copying the sheet itself rather than the contents. When I do it manually the imagees transfer fine. When I run the macro, it does pick up *something* - but instead of displaying the images, it looks like the error you might get on a webpage when an image fails to load.

Comment: Without any code I can't say for certain. However how you copy probably doesn't include shapes. This StackOverflow [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023212/how-to-copy-image-from-another-sheet-to-active-sheet) may help give you an idea. See the `Copy_Image` function

Comment: is the sheet in wbk_old protected ?

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier I thought you might be on to something there, because I have been playing around with protecting and unprotecting sheets. But, unfortunately, no it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An older question but since there doesn't seem to be an answer yet and since I just ran into the same problem: The solution is quite easy, although it has obvious other disadvantages.

If ScreenUpdating is set to False Excel doesn't seem to be able to copy pictures, so either don't deactivate ScreenUpdating at all or reactivate it before you copy your worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of the reasoning behind why that's happening.

Try manipulating your code using this as a guideline;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim picName As String
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row >= 5 Then
        picName = Target.Value
        Copy_Images picName
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Copy_Images(imageName As String)
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In Sheets(2).Shapes
        If sh.Name = imageName Then
            sh.Copy
            Sheets(1).Pictures.Paste
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly this does, please? - I'm not familiar with manipulating shapes and images in VBA.